# Call C# function from javaScript using CefSharp in Windows Form App

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp

How to call a C# function from JAVASCRIPT ( which is in HTML code, I am calling through CefSharp ) in Windows Form App

> CefSharp Components

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public ChromiumWebBrowser chromeBrowser;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Start the browser after initialize global component
        InitializeChromium();
    }

    public void InitializeChromium()
    {

        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();

        settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-media-stream", "1");

        Cef.Initialize(settings);

        chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("localhost/myproject/index.html");

        this.Controls.Add(chromeBrowser);

        chromeBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }
}
```

> Function To Be called By JS

```
public void Test(String message)
{
    MessageBox.Show(message, "Test");
}
```

> HTML Code Where I need to call Test() at onclick event

```
<span class="mySpan" onclick="<Some>.Test('It is working');"></span>
```

> **Code I Tried,**
>
> Inside InitializeChromium Function

```
CefSharpSettings.LegacyJavascriptBindingEnabled = true;

chromeBrowser.RegisterAsyncJsObject("boundAsync", new BoundObject());
```

> BoundObject.cs

```
public class BoundObject
{
    public void Test(String message)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(message, "Test");
    }
}
```

> HTML CODE

```
<span class="mySpan" onclick="boundAsync.Test('It is working');"></span>
```

But It doesn't work for me. Please let me know where am I wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you read the documentation? https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#javascript-integration

Comment: I did and using "RegisterAsyncJsObject" for this purpose. But, that doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Updated my question with the code, I am trying. Please check @amaitland

Comment: `boundAsync.Test` will be translated to `boundAsync.test` (You can control if names are camel cased when you register your object).

Answer (score 8):

Here is a tutorial
http://windowsapptutorials.com/wpf/call-c-sharp-javascript-using-cefsharp-wpf-app/

**1. Create a Class with the Method to be Invoked**

*Create a CallbackObjectForJs class that contains a showMessage function which would be invoked from javascript.*

```
public class CallbackObjectForJs{
    public void showMessage(string msg){//Read Note
        MessageBox.Show(msg);
    }
}
```

**2. Register the JS object**

*The next step is to register the JS object. This can be done by adding the following code in the `MainPage.xaml.cs` file.*

```
private CallbackObjectForJs _callBackObjectForJs;
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _callBackObjectForJs= new CallbackObjectForJs();
    ChromiumWebBrowser.RegisterAsyncJsObject("callbackObj", _callBackObjectForJs);
}
```

**3. Invoke the C# function from JavaScript**

*Next, simply invoke the C# function from your javascript code.*

```
<script>
    callbackObj.showMessage("Hello World!");
</script>
```

**Note:** *The name of the C# function should start with a small letter.*

---

**Alternative Solution** like suggested by `@amaitland`

Add an event listener to the browser instance:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    
    //Initialize ChromiumWebBrowser
    
    //Hook up event
    browser.JavascriptMessageReceived += OnBrowserJavascriptMessageReceived;
}

private void OnBrowserJavascriptMessageReceived(object sender, JavascriptMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    var windowSelection = (string)e.Message;
    //DO SOMETHING WITH THIS MESSAGE
    //This event is called on a CEF Thread, to access your UI thread
    //You can cast sender to ChromiumWebBrowser
    //use Control.BeginInvoke/Dispatcher.BeginInvoke
}
```

From javascript, invoke the `CefSharp.PostMessage` method (Which is automatically available within the `ChromiumWebBrowser` context:

```
//CefSharp.PostMessage can be used to communicate between the browser
//and .Net, in this case we pass a simple string,
//complex objects are supported, passing a reference to Javascript methods
//is also supported.
CefSharp.PostMessage(window.getSelection().toString());
```

Comment: If all you want to do is pass messages then you can use CefSharp.PostMessage with having to register an object, see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#JSEvent

Comment: ChromiumWebBrowser.RegisterAsyncJsObject("callbackObj", _callBackObjectForJs);
this method is deprecated. i think wanna update to your answer.

Comment: My upvote is for the alternative solution with is more concise and versatile (no dependance on a .NET class)

Answer (score 2):

Suggested method above is [deprecated](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2990)

Now it should be:

```cs
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    
    var browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("...");
    browser.JavascriptObjectRepository.Settings.LegacyBindingEnabled = true;
    browser.JavascriptObjectRepository.Register("callbackObj",
        new CallbackObjectForJs(), options: BindingOptions.DefaultBinder);
}
```