# Why won't CefSharp.PostMessage work in CefSharp browser?

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I tried using JavascriptMessageReceived event in c# to handle CefSharp.PostMessage called from JS within the browser. I even downloaded an example of this working from [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/communication-between-winforms-application-and-web-application-using-cefsharp-br/). Ran example which was supposed to do exactly what I needed, but it didn't work, nor does my code (below). Did CefSharp remove this functionality or change it? Do I need to enable this feature within the CefSettings or ChromiumWebBrowser?

```
using CefSharp;
using CefSharp.WinForms;

public ChromiumWebBrowser chromeBrowser;

public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string curDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
        Cef.Initialize(settings);
        chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(String.Format("file:///{0}/HelloWorld.html", curDir));
        chromeBrowser.JavascriptMessageReceived += ChromeBrowser_JavascriptMessageReceived;
    }

private void ChromeBrowser_JavascriptMessageReceived(object sender, JavascriptMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show((string)e.Message);
    }
```

HelloWorld.html here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
CefSharp.PostMessage("Hello world!");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `CefSharp.PostMessage("Hello world!");` is a quite new JS extension of 2020. Make sure your are using the actual CefSharp.
2. ```
   chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(String.Format("file:///{0}/HelloWorld.html", curDir));
   chromeBrowser.JavascriptMessageReceived += ChromeBrowser_JavascriptMessageReceived;
   ```

   The subscription on `JavascriptMessageReceived` events is too late, the page might be downloaded and JS might be executed to that moment. You should subscribe on events before page load.

   ```
   chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("about:blank");
   chromeBrowser.JavascriptMessageReceived += ChromeBrowser_JavascriptMessageReceived;
   chromeBrowser.Load(String.Format("file:///{0}/HelloWorld.html", curDir));
   ```
3. Make sure HelloWorld.html is existing in the application current working directory.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It worked! in conjunction with amaitland's answer!

Comment: Correct! But but there is a more complete answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66148896/11239018

Answer (score 1):

Where are you adding the ChromiumWebBrowser to the form? The WinForms ChromiumWebBrowser control won't load until it's handle is created which by default happens when it's added to a parent.

```cs
chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(String.Format("file:///{0}/HelloWorld.html", curDir));
chromeBrowser.JavascriptMessageReceived += ChromeBrowser_JavascriptMessageReceived;
Controls.Add(chromeBrowser);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It worked! in conjunction with 273K's answer!